# Showing that Karger's contraction algorithm has exponentially small probability of finding an optimum

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms

I'm stuck with one of my homework exercises:

> Consider the following variant of Karger’s algorithm for finding a minimum s-t cut, i.e., a minimum cut separating two specific given nodes s and t:
>
> As in the original algorithm, edges are iteratively contracted. In any iteration, let s and t denote the possibly contracted nodes that contain the original nodes s and t, respectively. To ensure that s and t do not get contracted, at each iteration any edges connecting s and t are deleted, and a random edge to contract is selected from the remaining edges.
>
> Give an example showing that the probability that this method finds a minimum s-t cut can be exponentially small.

I know how Karger's algorithm works, but I'm not sure why the probability is exponentially small and how can I show that by giving an example.

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Try to come up with a family of bad-case instances. A good way towards that can be to try and *prove* that the probability to find an optimal solution is better, and observe where the proof fails.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are the bad-case instances because of deleting edges between s and t?

Comment: That's your exercise and so you should come up with the example.

Comment: You can find detailed solution [here](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/ICCV2021/papers/Jenner_Extensions_of_Kargers_Algorithm_Why_They_Fail_in_Theory_and_ICCV_2021_paper.pdf) - Theorem 3.